# Let's frame the images

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was reading though some meta posts when I realized that the part of the 'post' I was reading was actually a screen shot included as part of the question. It is easy to confuse what is screenshot and what is post. It would be annoying for users to take a screenshot, edit it to include a border in it then post it. It wouldn't be too hard to give users the choice to set a border.

For example, the image below is hard to distinguish from the post on most browsers (except the blur):

[image: screenshot of this post]

It would be much more distinguishable if the image looked like this:

[image]

I realize that this problem is very minor. Any ideas on this? Is this feasible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In cases where I've felt the image needed to be distinguished from the background, I've used a block quote to add a border around it.

> [image]

```
> ![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7xM7.png)
```

Unfortunately, the automatic image scaling doesn't play nice with this.  It used to.